# Mapping maven structures to Eclipse structures, then analyzing with JDT

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to generate Java unit tests using Eclipse's JDT.  Part of that is determining the classpath that pertains to a particular Java class.

I imported a Maven project named jaffa-framework into Eclipse.  Jaffa-framework has several Maven modules, including jaffa-api.  Each of the submodules has its own pom.xml.  I can build jaffa-framework and its submodules with no problem using Maven from within Eclipse (although it will not build using `Project -> Build Project`).

```
<project ...
    <artifactId>jaffa-framework</artifactId>
    ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>normal</id>
            <modules>
                <module>jaffa-api</module>
                ...
            </modules>
       </profile>
    </profiles>
    ...
</project>
```

When I import jaffa-framework into Eclipse as a Maven project, I see the following in the UI:

- A Java project: jaffa-framework
- Two Folders/IPackageFragmentRoots for jaffa-api:
  jaffa-api/src/main/java and jaffa-api/src/test/java

  [image: jaffa-api source folders]
- One "plain" folder: jaffa-api

  [image: jaffa-api]

This structure looks weird to me.  I expected to see something more like:

```
jaffa-framework
  jaffa-api
    jaffa-api/src/main/java
    jaffa-api/src/test/java
```

Perhaps I did something wrong while importing?  If you have ideas, please let me know.

If I select a Java file within jaffa-api/src/main/java, I can use JDT to navigate to the jaffa-framework project and get its classpath using `javaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true)`; however, what I really need is the classpath for jaffa-api.

The jaffa-api folder contains a pom file, a .project file, and a .classpath file.  I don't see an easy way to navigate to it using JDT, and because it is a folder, I don't see how I could obtain the classpath programmatically using JDT.

I'm also wondering why jaffa-api looks like a plain folder, instead of something more project-like.  Eclipse must know that it is some kind of subproject, because the folder contains .classpath and .project files.

Please tell me how I can access the classpath information of jaffa-api using JDT, and/or how I can correct my project set up.

Answer (score 0):

There was something screwy about my original project creation.  I'm not sure what.

I solved my problem by deleting my jaffa-framework project by right-clicking on it and choosing "Delete" from the menu.  I re-imported the project using `File -> Open Projects from File System`.  I'm guessing the key thing to notice here is that the "Search for nested projects" box is checked.  After the project was reloaded, both jaffa-framework and jaffa-api appeared as projects.

[image: loading the project]